# Jaxb specify Marshaller for Endpoint

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, moxy, endpoint

I am using the Spring framework.

I have multiple mashallers and multiple endpoints. The Jaxb context for my marshallers are defined with xml-binding files (using the eclipselink-oxm-xml jaxbContextProperties) since I have multiple marshalling tasks. Using annotations was not a good solution because the same object requires a different marshalling/unmarshalling procedure depending on endpoint.

My configuration at the moment for a single JaxbMarshaller and Endpoint looks like so:

```
<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshallerA" unmarshaller="marshallerA"/>        

    <bean id="loggingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>


    <bean id="messageReceiver"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">
        <property name="endpointAdapters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter" 
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
            </list>
        </property>     
    </bean>  


    <bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshallerA" />
        <constructor-arg ref="marshallerA" />
    </bean> 


    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="myEndpointA"
        portTypeName="WebService"
        locationUri="/ws/myEndpointServiceA/"
        targetNamespace="http://company.com/schema/webServices" >

        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/path/to/schema/mySchemaA.xsd"/>

    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <bean id="marshallerA" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="x.y.z:x.y.w"/>
            <property name="jaxbContextProperties">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="eclipselink-oxm-xml">
                    <list>
                         <value>file:/bindingFileOne.xml</value>
                         <value>file:/bindingFileTwo.xml</value>
                         <value>file:/bindingFileThree.xml</value>    
                    </list>
                </entry>
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now say I have a second endpoint and a second marshaller, how can I force an Endpoint to use a specific marshaller?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up extending the DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter, creating SpecificEndpointAdapter. I only need to override one method, the implementation is as follows:

```
public class SpecificEndpointAdapter extends DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter {
    private List<Object> acceptedEndpoints;

    public void setAcceptedEndpoints(List<Object> acceptedEndpoints) {
        this.acceptedEndpoints = acceptedEndpoints;
    }

    @Override
        protected boolean supportsInternal(MethodEndpoint methodEndpoint) {
        if(acceptedEndpoints.contains(methodEndpoint.getBean()))
            return super.supportsInternal(methodEndpoint);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my context file, this allows me to restrict an endpoint adapter to a specific endpoint, thus having a specific marshaller:

```
<bean id="serviceAEndpointAdapter" class="my.package.SpecificEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="acceptedEndpoints">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceAEndpoint"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceA.marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceA.marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>     
</bean>    

<bean id="serviceBEndpointAdapter" class="my.package.SpecificEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="acceptedEndpoints">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceBEndpoint"/>
        </list>
    </property>      
    <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceB.marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="serviceB.marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

In my MarhsallingPayloadProcessor I can now declare which marshaller to use.  Note that I ended up using the bean id as the SpecificEndpointAdapter reference, so if you are using annotations, you will need to figure out the bean id of that endpoint.

I hope this helps anyone who was facing the same issue, let me know if the answer requires more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just clarifying some points of the accepted answer, you can make the reference do the Endpoint just receiving as parameter the endpoint, like a normal bean:

```
@Bean
public SpecificEndpointAdapter csvEndpointAdapter(MyEndpoint myEndpoint) {

    List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers =
            new ArrayList<>();
    argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor());

    List<MethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers =
            new ArrayList<>();
    returnValueHandlers.add(methodProcessor());

    SpecificEndpointAdapter specificEndpointAdapter = new SpecificEndpointAdapter();
    specificEndpointAdapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    specificEndpointAdapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);
    specificEndpointAdapter.setAcceptedEndpoints(Arrays.asList(myEndpoint));

    return specificEndpointAdapter;
}

private MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor() {
    return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller());
}

private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.company.application");
    marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
    return marshaller;
}
```

The `MyEndpoint`:

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {
   //...
}
```